# SQL - Insert Statement conflicting with Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, insert, conflict

I've got two tables, Enrolment and Attendance. The Primary Keys of Enrolment are UnitCode and StudentID. The Primary Keys of Assignment are UnitCode, StudentID (both of which are Foreign Keys to the same columns in Enrolment) and AssNo.

I've got a stored procedure named Insert Student Attendance:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertStudentAttendance

@unitCode varchar(4),
@studentID integer,
@date datetime

AS
    INSERT INTO Attendance
    (UnitCode, StudentID, AttDate, AttStatus)
    VALUES(@unitCode, @studentID, @date, 1)
    RETURN
```

Calling the procedure like so:

InsertStudentAttendance 'SIT101', 1, '2011-06-04'

Results in the error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Attendance_308E3499". The conflict occurred in database "db_test", table "dbo.Enrolment".
```

However, this only occurs when I use the stored procedure, not when I manually input the values into the exact same command. In Enrolment, there is a StudentID 1 enrolled in the UnitCode 'SIT101'. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to include the table information. "The Primary Keys of Enrolment are...." what?

Comment: How do you call the procedure, and what SQL did you use when you inserted manually? Did you remember to delete the row you inserted manually before calling the Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stored procedure declaration you have `@unitCode varchar(4)`, but it appears the value you are trying to insert is `SIT101`.

This will get silently truncated to `SIT1` which does not exist - hence the FK violation.

Increase the length of the parameter type to match that of the column.